# Server side rendering with Swig template, React and Express

Tags: express, reactjs, render, server-side, swig-template

This is the router I set up with Express:

```
var r = require('rethinkdb');
var quotes = require('../model/quotes');
var user = require('../model/users');
var auth = require('../lib/auth');
var React=require('react');
var ReactDOMServer=require('react-dom/server')
var Homepage=React.createFactory(require('../component/index.js').Homepage);

module.exports = function(app, passport) {

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        if (req.user) {
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        } else {
            var HomepageHTML=ReactDOMServer.renderToString(Homepage({}));
            res.render('index',{homepage:HomepageHTML});
        }
    });

}
```

In `index.html` view, written in Swig template engine:

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}

{% block title %}Homepage{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    {{homepage}}
{% endblock %}
```

It renders the string with tags, not the component I created with React, now what should I do to make Swig render the component I wrote?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `{{ homepage.toString() }}` ? I think this will solve the problem.